# I am facing image cut issue after upgrade Highchart version from 6.0.7 to 8.0.4

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I was using Highchart 6.0.7 version and Updated it to 8.0.4. I am using generate an image using phantom js with Highchart Converte JS. Previously it was working after upgrading the newer version facing image cutting issue.

Image width is cutting. I am passing both values `Exportorting` and `chart` height width.

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue on some online editor which I could work on and debug? A lot has changed from version 6.0.7 and just information about the issue is not enough to find a solution.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, I have tried that, it is working fine but if I do export with phantom it is not setting the height and half image cutting and in JPG it is showing half or more than half black portion create.

Comment: By the Highcharts Convert JS you mean the highcharts-convert.js script? This is a file that was used in the old version of Highcharts export server (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server) solution which is no longer supported. Have you tried the newer approach based on the NodeJS (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server)? Also, provide us with the method that you use to export charts.

Comment: @pawel_d So it will not work with the newer version of highchart versions?

Comment: @ManishSharma It might but there is no assurance it will. As I have mentioned, the old server is deprecated and it is no longer supported. If you want to be sure that everything works correctly, you should use the newest export server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I switched from Highcharts Version 7.0.2 to 8.0.4. The right side of the images were clipped. I solved the problem by patching highcharts-convert.js to always set the viewportSize instead of only adjusting the viewportSize for PDFs.

In highcharts-convert.js this was the original code

```
if (outType === 'pdf') {
    // redefine the viewport
    page.viewportSize = { width: clipwidth, height: clipheight };

    // simulate zooming to get the right zoomFactor. Using page.zoomFactor doesn't work anymore, see issue here https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685
    page.evaluate(function (zoom) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zoom = zoom;
    }, page.zoomFactor);

    page.paperSize = { width: clipwidth * dpiCorrection, height: clipheight * dpiCorrection };
}
```

I changed the code to this

```
// redefine the viewport
page.viewportSize = { width: clipwidth, height: clipheight };

if (outType === 'pdf') {
    //// redefine the viewport
    //page.viewportSize = { width: clipwidth, height: clipheight};

    // simulate zooming to get the right zoomFactor. Using page.zoomFactor doesn't work anymore, see issue here https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685
    page.evaluate(function (zoom) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zoom = zoom;
    }, page.zoomFactor);

    page.paperSize = { width: clipwidth * dpiCorrection, height: clipheight * dpiCorrection };
}
```

I hope this works as well for everyone else as it did for me.

Comment: I am facing this issue with jaon to png. Would it work for png?